# Linux function class_device_create changed to?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I use a 2.6.32 Kernel. It seems that the function `class_device_create()` changed.

But I can't find the corresponding function.

Comment: This question can be answered by a simple `git` query on the location of sysfs sources `drivers/base`, e.g.: `git log -Sclass_device_create -n 1 -p drivers/base`.

Comment: Don't work. I get this message `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New name is `device_create(...)`

Comment: Similarly, equivalent of `class_device_destroy()` is `device_destroy()` in the new kernel

Answer (score 0):

The function and all the class_device stuff were removed.

> commit c3b19ff06e0808555403491d61e8f0cbbb53e933
>   Author: Kay Sievers kay.sievers@vrfy.org 
>   Date:   Wed Mar 12 20:47:35 2008 +0100
>
> driver core: remove no longer used "struct class_device"
>
> Signed-off-by: Kay Sievers kay.sievers@vrfy.org
>      Signed-off-by: Greg Kroah-Hartman gregkh@suse.de